# How to check Facebook logged or not in Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to open app not have to login Facebook, I want to push some information to another activity by Push Extra. I know `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()`, but how to push extra with email, gender, name, phone number into another activity while AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null

Comment: Do yo want to pass access token to another activity right?

Comment: Yeah! And I want to get (email, gender, name, ...) to push extra into another Activity.